# FileMaker: Dropdown list with exact values in text

Tags: filemaker

I have a drop down list of subjects. Two particular subjects are Mathematics and Additional Mathematics. When I choose Mathematics from the drop down list, records from Additional Mathematics and Mathematics are both displayed. Worse is that records from Additional Mathematics are shown first. Many colleagues made mistakes because of this.

How do I make the drop down list such that when clicked, the exact terms are used instead?

Comment: You'll want to share more information about how this drop down list is being used. It sounds like it's being used as a search criteria. Is it part of a script that users use in Browse mode that performs a find automatically for the user? Do users enter Find mode, select the value from the drop down, and then perform the find? The answer is likely to prepend the search criteria with '==', but the best implementation will depend on how users are actually going about finding the records.

Comment: The user will enter Find mode to perform search. Most of my users will be using IWP to access, hence it is not possible to prepend the '==' sign. What other ways of making a 'Find' facility for my user are there in FileMaker do you recommend me to solve this problem?

Comment: With the regular client you could use an `OnModeExit` script trigger to catch when the user is exiting Find mode and insert the '==' then. With Advanced you could install a custom function into the `Perform Find` menu and insert the '==' then. IWP is a more difficult nut to crack for inserting the '=='. You could train your users to add the '==' themselves, or add a button for them to click to do it for them. I can't immediately think of a way to automatically prepend the '==' to an IWP find, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that is not necessarily unique to FileMaker. You are searching for a name that is imprecise because it is a match for multiple names. Rather instead you might want to search for a unique key **whose subject name** is 'Mathematics' as displayed in your drop down. It is the use of that unique key that allows you to perform a precise search, even when the name of one subject is a partial or complete match for another.

This solution requires you to add a unique serial number which is, in your case, to alter the Subjects table and add a field called 'idnumber' or similar. The field type should be *Number*, and the options should include *Auto-Enter-Serial number-Generate* and *On creation-increment by 1*. The trick here lies in making sure no two subjects have the same 'idnumber' even when you aren't paying attention, so set the *next value* to something greater than the number of subjects that already exist. Then from another layout assign each existing subject a unique idnumber, noting that if there are a great many subjects you could script that step.

I should mention that many recommend a best practice of never changing a production layout, but rather to duplicate the layout and make the required changes to the duplicate. This minimizes the effects of testing your changes etc.

Finally, change your layout in inspector such that the drop down list shows *Use values from field: 'idnumber'*. Select *Also display values from second field: 'Subject'* and *Show values only from second field*. Now your drop down is the same clean selection as before. The field will not look correct yet because it will show a number. To make it look correct you can insert another field, selecting 'Subject'. Place that field over top of the 'idnumber' and send 'idnumber' to the back. Fill the 'Subject' field with the correct background solid color instead of none, and enjoy your new precision search capability! The entire process is handled server side so it should not matter that client access is IWP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the selection to do a find, put an "==" before the text you're searching on. This will tell FileMaker to do an exact field contents search, instead of a "contains" search.